# Optimize writing a ctypes float array as byte stream to file from python

Tags: python, arrays, io, ctypes, writefile

I do have a small problem with the way I currently handle writing data to a file.
The data is stored as a ctypes pointer to an array of floats of a known size (over a 100 million).
The file itself is supposed to be a raw file that holds a certain amount of header info plus the representation of the above mentioned volume data as unsigned int.

What I currently do (after opening the file and writing the header information) is this:

```
texVolume = voxelData.from_address(ptr.as_pointer())
for pixel in texVolume.dataset_p.contents:
    f.write(c_uint8(int(pixel*255)))
f.close()
```

with voxelData being a ctypes struct holding (among other data) a ctypes float array pointer in the variable "dataset_p". This is the data I need to store as unsigned int bytes.

While my current implementation works just find, it is very slow and saving a file shouldn't be as slow as this.

I already tried doing the whole conversion from float to uint in bulk before the loop, but I can't seem to get it to work with the c_uint8 conversion anymore, throwing instead a TypeError ("only lenght-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars").

Thank you for any help you may provide. If anything is unclear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Do you have NumPy available?

Comment: You could probably improve performance, perhaps by a large amount, by writing many (1K-4K) pixels at once after first converting and storing groups or blocks of them in an array.

Comment: @eryksun : this is Python 3 and I do have access to NumPy.
martineau : I'll try this out, but why would it improve performance, since the same amount of single operations is executed on each pixel? Is the write function this slow (has such a big overhead)?

Comment: Try `f.write((255 * numpy.frombuffer(texVolume.dataset_p[0], dtype='float32')).astype('uint8'))`. Also consider using a larger buffer for the file by passing `buffering=65536` to the `open` function. That's 8 or 16 times larger than the default buffer size.

Comment: @eryksun : Awesome. This works like a charm. Thank you very much. If you want to put this in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Did increasing the file's buffer size help any, or is the speed-up mostly due to NumPy?

Comment: From a quick time.time() test:
original:   84.4s
buffer:     84.1s
numpy:   0.6s
np+buf:   0.57s